# Aws Lambda handle cold start requests differently

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using provisioned lambdas for running my application. The initialisation time for my function is quite high. I was wondering if there was a way to check at runtime if the lambda under consideration was a provisioned one or not. If it isn't a provisioned lambda I would like to handle the request in a very lean manner cutting out a lot of activities done during initialisation and during the actual request handling to provide a degraded experience.

Also it seems unlikely but could I essentially spin off a different background thread during the initialisation phase to take care of the heavy activities and have a flag implemented in my code that checks if the initialisation is complete. If it isn't and I start processing the request, I go ahead with the degraded experience otherwise I fulfill my request normally. I am not sure how the background thread will behave in Lambda.

Comment: What language are you using? If you're for example going with a node + express app you're able to decide on what to do in the handler function, before the express app would actually be initialised. Problem on this one: You can't have any background activity. If you return the callback & send some response to the client, your lambda function will "terminate" in the sense that all threads are paused. So if there are some events left in the event loop, they will be finished (or continued) when the next request invokes the function.

Comment: @tpschmidt I am using Java

Comment: There it would be the same. You can set a global variable in the handler function so you know whether this was the first invoke. But as I said, this does not solve your problem cause all "side"-threads will be paused when the main threads returns the response to the client. I guess you're trying to get around of the slow responses cause by cold start requests.

Comment: @tpschmidt exactly. Also another concern is with the provisioned lambdas. They are initialised before a request comes in. So will the background thread started during initialisation phase be completely executed or would it be in a "paused" state and resume when the first request comes in. Ideally would want some sort of env variable to indicate if it's a provisioned lambda or not

Comment: FYI, similar topic: [Shave 99.93% off your Lambda bill with this one weird trick](https://medium.com/@hichaelmart/shave-99-93-off-your-lambda-bill-with-this-one-weird-trick-33c0acebb2ea)